# Why do I get a circle when I try to buffer a squared polygon with turf.js?

Tags: turf

I have created the following node.js code with turf.js:

```js
const turf = require('@turf/turf')

let polygon = [
  [
    [ -46.70527960466082, -23.515693805007327 ],
    [ -46.70525061354379, -23.515706130219414 ],
    [ -46.70521688456519, -23.515720493550234 ],
    [ -46.70515408370665, -23.51574718295358 ],
    [ -46.70514380411614, -23.51575153885141 ],
    [ -46.70534467952754, -23.51614450729978 ],
    [ -46.70550423529982, -23.516075408203687 ],
    [ -46.705303857919084, -23.515683517916514 ],
    [ -46.70527960466082, -23.515693805007327 ]
  ]   
]  
let turfPolygon = turf.polygon(polygon)
let bufferedPolygon = turf.buffer(turfPolygon, 500, {units: 'meters'})

console.log(JSON.stringify(bufferedPolygon))
```

On this code, `polygon` is a polygon that doesn`t have a circular shape. However, the result that I get from this code is the following JSON:

```json
{"type":"Feature","properties":{},"geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[-46.70322088458993,-23.511612661040875],[-46.70324513725736,-23.511602374268882],[-46.70414989865253,-23.511313190193746],[-46.70509871194889,-23.51119085258346],[-46.70605535658333,-23.51124003161756],[-46.70698331312504,-23.51145884991158],[-46.70784715697299,-23.511838954163927],[-46.70861391032006,-23.51236583394781],[-46.70925430084214,-23.51301937549594],[-46.70974387910988,-23.51377462936544],[-46.709944266799546,-23.514166513971112],[-46.71026468528243,-23.51499591890971],[-46.710402822262445,-23.515866661757098],[-46.71035338468864,-23.516745400734823],[-46.71011826193278,-23.517598487221015],[-46.70970645400013,-23.51839325424125],[-46.70913372739746,-23.519099267466057],[-46.70842201176066,-23.51968949079388],[-46.70759856029236,-23.520141321856958],[-46.70743900069192,-23.52021042308697],[-46.70653192465988,-23.520507341986136],[-46.70557904934411,-23.520635970913354],[-46.704617132929336,-23.520591347859405],[-46.70368328247596,-23.520375194211702],[-46.702813522046306,-23.5199958483299],[-46.70204140267023,-23.519467943791756],[-46.70139670784378,-23.518811844738906],[-46.70090430454788,-23.51805286013362],[-46.70070343947814,-23.517659885989946],[-46.70038195533657,-23.516825929817898],[-46.700244732646844,-23.51595040311668],[-46.700297077557394,-23.515067184373397],[-46.700536960877805,-23.514210449042604],[-46.700955097169526,-23.513413347175494],[-46.701535304545,-23.51270672082495],[-46.70225513117563,-23.51211791083629],[-46.703086724211424,-23.511669699162645],[-46.70309392009424,-23.511666649982637],[-46.703187958960925,-23.511626656930865],[-46.70322088458993,-23.511612661040875]]]}}
```

Going on https://geojson.io and seeing its result I see the following shape:

[image]

I don't get why I'm getting a circle instead of a polygon that follows the shape of my input `polygon`. What am I getting wrong? Why `turf.buffer` is returning a circular shaped polygon?

Comment: try 10m or 50m - without seeing how big your polygon is I would suspect it is too small to make a difference at 500m

Comment: @IanTurton Ah yeah, I've realized now that the `buffer` makes the edges curved. Do you know if there's any way of making a buffer in a way that it doesn't create these circular patterns on the edges? Or I should be looking at different functions for that?

Comment: buffering inherently will create curved edges. Consider what happens at a vertex of the original polygon. The locus of points that is the buffer distance away is a circular arc. There's nothing else it could be. Maybe you're looking for transformScale, which preserves the shape, just scales it to a new size.

Comment: @Llaves You're right, after thinking a little about it... The buffer function is already doing what I need. I just got a little confused when I saw the circle with the buffer distance being too huge.

Comment: Simply because the buffer is so big compared to the polygon https://i.imgur.com/xEvwroR.png

Comment: Here's a another way to think about a buffer - imagine taking a circle whose diameter equals your buffer distance and roll that along the outside boundary of your polygon. The area traced by the interior  of the rolling circle is the buffer. When the circle is large compared to your polygon, you will get the result you saw, which is easily mistaken for a circle.

Comment: Some buffer algorithms have advanced options like endcap style or join type. See images in https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Buffer.html.